# No puedo hacer lista anidada con los múltiplos para hacer las tuplas

Tags: python, lista

> Crea una lista de 20 tuplas de tamaño 2. La primera entrada será un
> número entero entre 1 y 20 y la segunda entrada contendrá una lista
> con los 10 primeros múltiplos del número entero correspondiente. Por
> último, muestra las tablas de multiplicar del 1 al 20 con el formato
> “1 x 1 = 1”

Esto es el código que estoy haciendo, pero no puedo hacer lista anidada con los múltiplos para hacer las tuplas.

```py
tabla_desde = 1 #tablas del 1...
tabla_hasta = 20 #...al 10
desde = 1 #multiplicaciones desde el 1...
hasta = 10 #...hasta el 10
li = []
l2 = []
lista = []
for factor1 in range(tabla_desde, tabla_hasta +1):
    print("tabla de multiplicar {}".format(factor1))
    li.append(factor1)
    for factor2 in range(desde, hasta + 1):
        l2.append(factor1 * factor2)
        
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(factor1, factor2, (factor1 * factor2)))
        lista.append(l2)



items = zip(li, lista)
print(tuple(items))

print(li)
print(l2)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Una vez hayas terminado el bucle `for` que va construyendo `l2` tienes que hacer `li.append(tuple(l2)` y despues `lista.append(tuple(li))`. El resultado buscado quedará en `lista` y no necesitarás luego hacer el `zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construir listas anexando elementos no es la única forma de crearlas. En un caso como el planteado, la solución más simple es usar compresión de listas:

```py
lista = [(i, [i*n for n in range(1, 11)]) for i in range(1, 21)]
```

Tenemos por un lado `i` que varía de 1 a 20. Para cada uno, se crea una tupla `(i, [i*n ...])` que es la que nos pide el ejercicio de un valor y la lista de los 10 primero múltiplos de éste.

Para mostrar la tabla en el formato especificado:

```py
for i in range(1, 21):
    for n in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{i} x {n} = {i*n}")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. funciona.